# AsyncTask Android Force Closes App

Tags: android, android-listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Runtime Verify Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280551/android-runtime-verify-error)

I'm trying to get an app to display a list of available videos from a channel on YouTube called illbehonest. What am I doing wrong? I'm using a Java-JSON library to do that. The application force closes every time I try to go to the VideoPlay activity (whose name has no relation to its function, by the way). Here's the code:

```
package com.aer.illbehonest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class VideoPlay extends Activity {   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_play);

        new ShowTitlesTask().execute("");
    }

    class ShowTitlesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        ArrayList<String> titlesList;

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args) {

            URL jsonURL = null;
            try {
                jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/illbehonest/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
            URLConnection jc = null;
            try {
                jc = jsonURL.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
                InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = jc.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String jsonTxt = null;
            try {
                jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);

            JSONObject jdata = json.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray jentry = jdata.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int entryNumber = 0; entryNumber<=25; entryNumber++){
                    JSONObject entry = jentry.getJSONObject(entryNumber);
                    titlesList.add(entry.getString("title"));
            }

            return titlesList;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        ListView listView = (ListView)VideoPlay.this.findViewById(R.id.videolist);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (VideoPlay.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, titlesList);
            (listView).setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the LogCat output:

```
01-14 16:58:36.699: W/dalvikvm(11938): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/sf/json/JSONException; (1034)

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): Link of class 'Lnet/sf/json/JSONException;' failed

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 813 (Lnet/sf/json/JSONException;)

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2e

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): VFY:  rejected Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;.toJSON (Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/sf/json/JsonConfig;)Lnet/sf/json/JSON;

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x002e

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): VFY:  rejected Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;.toJSON (Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/sf/json/JsonConfig;)Lnet/sf/json/JSON;

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): Verifier rejected class Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;

01-14 16:58:36.707: W/dalvikvm(11938): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b28930)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net/sf/json/JSONSerializer

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at com.aer.illbehonest.VideoPlay$ShowTitlesTask.doInBackground(VideoPlay.java:63)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at com.aer.illbehonest.VideoPlay$ShowTitlesTask.doInBackground(VideoPlay.java:1)
01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)

01-14 16:58:36.707: E/AndroidRuntime(11938):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: There's existing answer to your question right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280551/android-runtime-verify-error

Comment: @Bostone I switched the libraries over but it's still force closing. I'm going to update my question with the new LogCat output.

Comment: @Bostone Actually the output is about the same, because of JSONSerializer, but it isn't in org.json.... what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSONException but you haven't included any JSONException handlers.

and yes, Android has its own JSON library, although GSON comes with a nice convenient serializer which saves a lot of coding time if you need store objects with a lot of keys